# Magento Observer object not containing anything

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have an observer method that triggers upon the event `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after`, basically when a credit memo was created. The method I have fires:

```
public function handleCreditmemoCreation(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //$observer contains data passed from when the event was triggered.
        $fp = fopen('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento-1/var/log/request.log', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $observer->getData());
        fwrite($fp, 'test');
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

However, `$observer->getData()` doesn't output anything into the request.log log file. To confirm I configured the file correctly, I write the string 'test' to the file, which works.

Also, when I check $observer for null, it tells me that $observer is not null. Does anyone know why then it does not seem to contain anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access observer passed data you'd always use `$observer->getEvent()`

```
$observer->getEvent()->getData(XXX)
```

Where XXX is variable, as every event can contain different data

In your case, if you browse `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo` class, you will find this properties

```
protected $_eventPrefix = 'sales_order_creditmemo';
protected $_eventObject = 'creditmemo';
```

First of them tells us the event prefix this model will use when firing standard Magento model events. For instance: **sales_order_creditmemo**_save_after (yours), **sales_order_creditmemo**_delete_before, etc...

The second tells us the object passed in that events. So, in your concrete case, you can access creditmemo object this way...

```
$observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
$observer->getEvent()->getData('creditmemo'); // same result
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. I tried your code; however, I still get no data:(

Comment: You can update your question with the updated code, so I can see what are you trying to do. For instance, you cannot log a XXX->getData() as a string, cause it is not a string. Do a print_r(XXX->getData()), and then check what info do you want to log

Comment: ok, it worked. Thanks a lot. It turns out that fwrite() can only log strings as you mentioned. Using print_r, I was able to print the returned array to a log file.